# How use getElementsByTagName() if element has this or that class?

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I have many elements `<img>` and i want to exatrapolate only them with class **"A"** or class **"B"** (not elements with class **"C"**).

I want to do this for parsing of web page with PHP.

This my code:

```
$doc = file_get_html('https://www.example.com');
foreach($doc-> getElementById('content')-> getElementsByTagName('img') as $item){   
}
```

how can i extrapolate `img` with class **.A** or **.B** ?

```
foreach($doc-> getElementById('content')-> getElementsByTagName('img[class="A" OR "B"]') as $item){
}
```

thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: If the duplicate doesn't work for what you are trying, then please create a new question with code which shows the problem you have can be used by others to reproduce the problem.  At the moment it is difficult to know the exact HTML you are using as we can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

How about with `find()`?

```
foreach($doc->getElementById('content')->find("img[class='A'][class='B']") as $item)
{
   // other code goes here 
}
```

Comment: If you look in the source for simple html dom you can see that it's the same thing - `function getElementsByTagName($name, $idx=null) {return $this->find($name, $idx);}`

Comment: @NigelRen thank you sir, I didn't know that!

Comment: @AlwaysSunny sorry but not works... :/

Comment: @AlwaysSunny your code works only if img has both class... but in my case should work if has class "A" OR class "B"

Comment: @NigelRen  code suggested works only if img has both class... but in my case should work if has class "A" OR class "B"